# Unable to install rpy2 on Windows - Python to R package for Python

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Python version - 3.6
R version - 3.3

Command i'm using for install - `pip install rpy2`

it exits with this error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\blah\Temp\pip-build-7cfnztfk\rpy2\

When I log the output to a file. This is what I see-

```
Collecting rpy2
  1 location(s) to search for versions of rpy2:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/03/6f/3ef727c0803a4cda74b6baa0469bc775e66752f36f8b8f9fe426fcd56b4f/rpy2-2.0.8.tar.gz#md5=c63a56aca8a352719ee3c91805beee66 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.0.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/04/1e/ec260f547e8624c5eba8b7ee05d19a0d38fdf53e276ed26f8660591fc1f3/rpy2-2.4.2.tar.gz#md5=25193dedeb8e47f63217b8c83b847a85 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.4.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/10/50/222aebde292dcd0853d43d9389212b4b111758859d16b6d10a555968e923/rpy2-2.7.9.tar.gz#md5=4315a3fbe765cea54d252899384390c8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/12/29/01cca39f022291fe2436f2a5890131aa791e9af1cf0f090cb7ed884fa6f7/rpy2-2.3.3.tar.gz#md5=6cd95eb70645577cb53198ef0a32395e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/17/6c/17f0cec2fff47ffc1b6019c4967c5858b3efa78894451995da8fbbfdf1fe/rpy2-2.3.10.tar.gz#md5=9db1b8be710f1b6eee8974a956185c37 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.10
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/19/e2/b8c5d022b58ba115377f1fa745cdefa63b6546d3bcbe173b339ab9577d7e/rpy2-2.1.1.tar.gz#md5=da5f58597a7ced6d9480c6fe563a2a40 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/1c/b5/37859f3995b17db989cd5b65cef388e97e9bd34272209c4628a22461c995/rpy2-2.7.6.tar.gz#md5=e2fdcbc5bbd3803256c39568c423dcd9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/1e/bc/88b60b108c5c67463e00e56bee66b2004b0f8cb77c76b411d86060885768/rpy2-2.1.8.tar.gz#md5=378c053f5eac7e96c500c8ebcac00a42 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/1f/66/67b15d820b737ca7c871ba111dd3c1276fb5564f267ecd5cdd01b1707ec8/rpy2-2.5.3.tar.gz#md5=6adef51aa9ddd8cfcd63798f875244f9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.5.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2a/8e/27f782e9febf4e358145e78ac6f9c65535a154da9193ea7f80c8da37d67b/rpy2-2.8.3.tar.gz#md5=9e5c76f311ce19b549683f0279b9663b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.8.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2b/ee/cadd2702b3d0a65cc765c7fb1d6515fd47a9422b3ffcb9912a810fa43774/rpy2-2.5.5.tar.gz#md5=c874bebbe775e3cdc926a1da00252c37 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.5.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2e/01/a75652392524b4a33639f78c73c6d18ef68a09e4708575c8611ad2e6e91e/rpy2-2.1.6.tar.gz#md5=d2cb7db347057c4a9d128139b686f976 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2e/ca/d0c87dbb6103dabce5d58c38965119407148999fb228754d9585a867afaa/rpy2-2.5.1.tar.gz#md5=d1f77b439093655faf473105b17ba9d2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.5.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/31/c1/fc4bb5a68d7d9ae2fc85f3b6a0a8dcb46a2809530222560a990df0c78bd7/rpy2-2.1.9.tar.gz#md5=afe629914e7263900e5d15d419f69865 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/32/22/115048816e0d29ec80adcaf97b03dc20c021928fcb70426904e32179031a/rpy2-2.7.8.tar.gz#md5=56ca162bca76bb9c3f935f099c916196 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/33/69/9ff5a1fd10211fae3ad4410db07ac560d3b47f56dd42ee8ad2cba34f058e/rpy2-2.6.1.dev0.tar.gz#md5=78e0a52c885cb49c8f87b39fdd2a2614 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.6.1.dev0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/38/d1/d4f21552dbaf7a7c5cc4c3b54c51d7a937b928f4cf19686e5a18c9c6a833/rpy2-2.1.4.tar.gz#md5=cf4e0d80ba498a6d76f107531966478d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3b/3d/9d0f039757dc8551bd9f5ef0c52d7bc267183e0e8bbf5c903a584bb8d07b/rpy2-2.2.7.tar.gz#md5=6b8e32b66fcb60490022e3bc840b96ec (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3c/3e/d3063b5cb4c6494eb77f6a62a24c0c996551e7fd4fdea094613d27ef8373/rpy2-2.1.0.tar.gz#md5=90737bf49d9d340937921fbc85dbf364 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3d/9b/b76b3665936204e14174dcac4814d8c91c833e9c3164664d5e89d777dac5/rpy2-2.7.0.tar.gz#md5=afd9ea81a03640b60240b7d53518e652 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/93/1e249b17f1b76aa846da2ad6202cde34c3f0954cd5bed11c14c8f13f33ab/rpy2-2.8.2.tar.gz#md5=729946166b43103db7697e69db8c5c45 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.8.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/94/33af884d35a9659af1fc7576b108c3a938b48de52814622a58362e53977c/rpy2-2.3.9.tar.gz#md5=86851a56f637e7b87709eb2b91dc5075 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/4b/a1/f4b62c9a4c52857520768a50fa1a50e50f4308e72432875e799ccb172aa9/rpy2-2.7.4.tar.gz#md5=62e6037388078a3bcf47642771e043ef (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/4d/b8/8f4d9a7e5df21cea45abaf638ded72f7d64327be27fb827eb0288c012b05/rpy2-2.3.0.tar.gz#md5=ad140fc1a1280cf394e4d8dedbcfaaba (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/50/df/c8a034ac1cce7acf11eab7d3ce77346f2b00e3002d40c07953b99428c6c2/rpy2-2.1.2.tar.gz#md5=b0d74cedcf05f777bf91f0f08aad015a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/58/72/96024f6d612a932072769408a232ed6a6d851a9b45c6f02204dce5d92230/rpy2-2.3.4.tar.gz#md5=38fa0fb1b2543e65655ced3d6741ba68 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/5b/06/b762808433fbca4e54f22a41f1610535667e52750f1726be3a8943418fdf/rpy2-2.6.3.tar.gz#md5=131f5f089d7fa1b18f8d03c90d9c88df (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.6.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/6b/7b/ab970547f09811da19200886a10af04e0535811e1ca9ed7f5033e4dd9c45/rpy2-2.6.2.tar.gz#md5=e057dff11ffe42351ceeb65375dbfc9b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.6.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/6c/53/28733799a55c8de721e2e9ed408e4b0b4a12860f27fe2beea64f8826516d/rpy2-2.2.0.tar.gz#md5=a42a7f1e6ddb10dc3a1886c2f4309fab (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/72/15/dc243f32266f98b477b9d48f1f5d8d16a7832454679b43e6389bb4fa2c14/rpy2-2.4.3.tar.gz#md5=57e3fda409226dffb543c913c8553cdc (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.4.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/72/e4/ed07b5fe8be72697c55d1c3b8ef5dea2e616c8e4f0c55f785c25c99f5865/rpy2-2.2.4.tar.gz#md5=0192a3c05d8d97971e2bcf888944aff5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/75/a4/182f9dc82934768680b663968115cc3e7e4a1be24478cbb2e1ed44e22b60/rpy2-2.4.0.tar.gz#md5=6e09d88e1fdd4afb8b6274fa302053fa (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.4.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/7f/14/c79d69df276f67effe19c79749635e0345a154734bd42e62212d7adeca28/rpy2-2.2.3.tar.gz#md5=70d2181168b3ba9168bab48654f4028d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/81/86/4bfa5d7ee0027ebe3d6d0b02151448f7d7e74cb3b5c628c99b3cef1a8cdf/rpy2-2.3.2.tar.gz#md5=b811810ece66adde25f9ed0ecb2733e5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/81/f6/3ef71cc570252d10dc6ec4c08b7bb492f7427aa92f400046f38d77c4b533/rpy2-2.1.3.tar.gz#md5=51544f516942b99f4825dbe776049b1c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/86/cf/1a8fc078fb2cfdaeb03cf2c5b8ffc111680d25bb8ce5cf6e488312693298/rpy2-2.1.5.tar.gz#md5=957928621002593ca9b85b94ce8c790a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/89/83/3b6a957bc82bbdeb2fddc3891e756ded109c1c3adfa7a34eeac4f74eca46/rpy2-2.8.1.tar.gz#md5=dd6dc7198e27a4771e66af022ab6bcf2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.8.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/8d/54/bd4732701374868ef0a4ebbaa1c6e5137ef4235a3c0469d31ca39ccc811a/rpy2-2.4.4.tar.gz#md5=58fd357ba922839b65fd67766319b806 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.4.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/8d/f5/7f0387d8f3ada4208f308459ae3ec929fd7da4d656ec77aef1cfda34e5f1/rpy2-2.3.1.tar.gz#md5=8d68dbd8947931975304dc633bbb843c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/8e/c1/d7828132ee6db4a8214b08114868d1c6cc590e4cc968e215101301b328ea/rpy2-2.3.0beta1.tar.gz#md5=9f75b07ccb916911ab810ec40f6870b0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.0beta1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/98/ba/895121e08c67163efe3245c660931d72e538f8555ef63eb8982128791c6f/rpy2-2.7.5.tar.gz#md5=459118a2eebdaa362157ae09637b4f77 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/9b/12/966d1c73ff5fa94b82c59d8f2728b0edb93525a200fdae5e59973f9580d7/rpy2-2.5.4.tar.gz#md5=115a20ac30883f096da2bdfcab55196d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.5.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/a3/f4/8e3eaadd97fb53ce105d46d6da5e889370eb3215a5c3c7258124c915e5c1/rpy2-2.5.6.tar.gz#md5=a36e758b633ce6aec6a5f450bfee980f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.5.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/a8/47/171d97aa925d3fa13f43788a1670ab0febbaf3ede17784f00f326eeec5f4/rpy2-2.5.2.tar.gz#md5=65f865ae50c223f44d058d7cddf0ff87 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.5.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/aa/18/e5eb0feabaf90a57a36e33cdbedd5c5db139c647b01710443f72d9b3ede9/rpy2-2.3.6.tar.gz#md5=d64aed40e7b92581eb859890b291e88c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/b1/fd/94e1bb028bd455bddf2a6ba5c6d9b23af72c223aef81100518cfa107549f/rpy2-2.2.2.tar.gz#md5=7690d8fa747e62cd27cfacfa45f4a07b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/b4/4b/be413652e888c132a5548b523df4ebd11ee310111bb6f4477f26fef00869/rpy2-2.7.7.tar.gz#md5=be93432426744cdae8a0e5d2b157d371 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/b8/d2/8ea6a35c67e52dc1dbe9aa890d80fae77a9d3cfb1282588905a90df622e5/rpy2-2.7.2.tar.gz#md5=6503f4afda56f5f5182c2839a9ce12e9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/b9/17/c813ec2bc0b42be495153cb61e345fde74330b9e5c2126af12139e83c1a8/rpy2-2.4.1.tar.gz#md5=9f693909c80e8df9d6a1ffbefa8b13f0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.4.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/bc/90/c8d2af086dfeaa9aabdeb4da9e196ac06a3187b1943e20fc9cd17cb3d885/rpy2-2.2.1.tar.gz#md5=422a31a1b3cf36efafdae53306f7f422 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/bf/be/130a02cdf1400da1a767f323f7133822b76e2541bacd8399729984f7a4b7/rpy2-2.3.8.tar.gz#md5=f331120aeeb1b27118d4e3360f2ec45d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/c1/72/8387d9ca041ba15abb65a0c1b0bec34f6cb5535c007d4895c4d6c73c3de7/rpy2-2.3.7.tar.gz#md5=e71efa65b66ede146a766ae7d753a7f6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/c1/e2/1b33ab520b012e62bca598c42a5433a334b710ab4e6a9409ae5cb5f09f04/rpy2-2.6.1.tar.gz#md5=2febe7862a9a4fa0a43fc3f6851823e6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/c2/f0/64c87e45f5ead2bbfb078c92f3d73ce7cf7fd9cda49e3487b284e3213850/rpy2-2.1.7.tar.gz#md5=e8e8db05f13644ce04784888156af471 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/c3/ce/dc91e8879b84771fda231b0a1b46e09615bd072d1d2b135b3ee5913b66c3/rpy2-2.8.0.tar.gz#md5=cfb51aa4429f81b54afd13dca06b9749 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.8.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cc/e9/caa964783c1cc7085eae7a5bf442c0972bfa7700bdd1d682629354444d3e/rpy2-2.7.1.tar.gz#md5=3aa1d45940816e4902a1172f7ef76708 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cd/87/4e29e47711d81d897e5f2ea546a31e555ec11a9bb38360c04cbe3c2f5866/rpy2-2.5.0.tar.gz#md5=2cd4aa3599e2f4b1f5a9bff159462e70 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.5.0
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/d5/c2/9f2161125387391c6381437dd42391c18e4e8b126fcf7abdad93a8b47d9b/rpy2-2.0.8.win32-py2.6.msi#md5=2c8d174862c0d132db0c65777412fe04 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/); unsupported archive format: .msi
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/d8/de/994dcb74ad4000d24272f83957108b3f7d93f469abc279b22bd37707902c/rpy2-2.6.0.tar.gz#md5=679898fbc832d4f05a5efcf1a7eb1a68 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.6.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/62/9c890fddc7e35c3f4787135a947c43b7df1942c6d950c437291afa6a3aae/rpy2-2.2.5.tar.gz#md5=aa9c0c3120716705b28127323cc4ac6d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/e2/fb/af039db4ca81bc0f4b84908463de2056152d3c3e13519096f9aa3147e150/rpy2-2.3.0alpha1.tar.gz#md5=1fe4d18abe4140900ed812d091bbd913 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.0alpha1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/ed/8f/f937bf310e9d5049bf3cf6cab4b09db0dec3e381bd8ad5d433646a1492a2/rpy2-2.3.5.tar.gz#md5=56341b6f425149b60765b19641e953a4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/f0/a9/df46e47df182d3333a8b1c45de407fd29dc131df2c7f46740c0706e7cba9/rpy2-2.2.6.tar.gz#md5=32d73a3e4acb915ce15d958c9092dcb8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/f7/92/3ec3ebf8a1714ea7af978133f5f4044b7bcfa2690df7ff1038f300d4a698/rpy2-2.7.3.tar.gz#md5=0b2d767d121e972c0111e3c2c2add56f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.7.3
  Using version 2.8.3 (newest of versions: 2.0.8, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.3.10, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.5.5, 2.5.6, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.7.7, 2.7.8, 2.7.9, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3)
  Using cached rpy2-2.8.3.tar.gz
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/2a/8e/27f782e9febf4e358145e78ac6f9c65535a154da9193ea7f80c8da37d67b/rpy2-2.8.3.tar.gz#md5=9e5c76f311ce19b549683f0279b9663b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/)
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\anajla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lk0l19z0\rpy2\setup.py) egg_info for package rpy2
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
    Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

    R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
    You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
    GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
    For more information about these matters see
    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

    'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
    C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-33~1.0\bin\x64\R CMD config --ldflags
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\anajla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lk0l19z0\rpy2\setup.py", line 331, in <module>
        ri_ext = getRinterface_ext()
      File "C:\Users\anajla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lk0l19z0\rpy2\setup.py", line 238, in getRinterface_ext
        ldf = shlex.split(' '.join(rexec.cmd_config('--ldflags')))
      File "C:\Users\anajla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lk0l19z0\rpy2\setup.py", line 191, in cmd_config
        universal_newlines = True)
      File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 639, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 721, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('C:\\PROGRA~1\\R\\R-33~1.0\\bin\\x64\\R', 'CMD', 'config', '--ldflags')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Cleaning up...
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\anajla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lk0l19z0\rpy2\
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 310, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 750, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 601, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 425, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "c:\users\anajla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 718, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\anajla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lk0l19z0\rpy2\
```

Comment: I've managed to get past the above error by installing cygwin. However, now I'm getting another error "R was not built as a library"

Comment: Got around that and finally ran into this: rpy2 will not compile on my machine and throws this at my face "  c:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-build-7fh04kdv\rpy2\rpy\rinterface\sequence.c(522): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'R_len_t', possible loss of data
    .\rpy\rinterface\_rinterface.c(209): error C2370: 'NAInteger_Type': redefinition; different storage class"

Comment: It seems to be looking for a very specific version of R (3.3.1). Is that the version you have installed?

Comment: Ok, I see it running R. Something is trying to shell out ` 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I needed cygwin to get past the 'sh' error. I'm stuck on something else now. It appears that this package's code is not able to compile on my machine. See my last comment.

Comment: Can I ask how did you get around "R was not built as a library"? @NajlaAugust